# I can't download objconv, Is this a PATH issue?

Tags: linux, shell, path, gnu

I'm using objconv to compile an Object file (*.o*) to nasm assembly (*.asm*).
I run the build.sh as so: `./build` But it's not working. I try to type in `objconv -h` but that doesn't work. Error: `objconv: command not found` I wonder if this has to do with the PATH or if i'm running build.sh wrong. Can anyone help??

Comment: If your file is named `build.sh` then you'd have to run `./build.sh`. If you've downloaded/built `objconv` and can't figure out how to add it to your PATH, you can run it by specifying the absolute file path to it instead.

Comment: that is `/my/crazy/path/where/I/installed/that/pkg/ojbconv` ;-) . Good luck.